# Is this proof actually true?

Tags: proof-verification

[Link](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20170427094749AAX7jLL)

> If a tribonacci sequence has 20 as its second seed and 17 as its third seed, find all positive integers that can be its first seed so that 2017 appears as a term somewhere in the sequence. 
>   Note: Tribonicca is the sequence of number the fourth onwards is the sum of the previous three terms. 
>   For example: the first 3 numbers called seeds are 1, 2, 3. The next number is 6 then next one is 11 and so on.
>
> Let (ₙ) be the tribonacci sequence defined by:
>      { ₁ = 
>      { ₂ = 20
>      { ₃ = 17
>      { ₙ₊₃ = ₙ + ₙ₊₁ + ₙ₊₂ 
>   where  is an unknown positive integer.
>
> Thus: 
>      ₄ =  + 37          → If it is equal to 2017, then =1980        ◄◄◄ VALID
>
> ₅ =  + 74          → If it is equal to 2017, then =1943        ◄◄◄ VALID
>
> ₆ = 2 + 128      → If it is equal to 2017, then =944.5       ◄◄◄ INVALID   (not integral)
>
> ₇ = 4 + 239      → If it is equal to 2017, then =444.5       ◄◄◄ INVALID
>    (not integral)
>
> ₈ = 7 + 441      → If it is equal to 2017, then ≈225.143    ◄◄◄ INVALID
>    (not integral)
>
> ₉ = 13 + 808    → If it is equal to 2017, then =93             ◄◄◄ VALID
>
> ₁₀ = 24 + 1488 → If it is equal to 2017, then ≈22.0417    ◄◄◄ INVALID (not integral)
>
> ₁₁ = 44 + 2737 → If it is equal to 2017, then ≈-16.364     ◄◄◄ INVALID (negative)
>
> ... 
>   and any higher term will obviously yield a negative .
>
> So if: 
>       = 93     → ₉ = 2017 
>       = 1943 → ₅ = 2017 
>       = 1980 → ₄ = 2017 
>   and obviously, if: 
>       = 2017 → ₁ = 2017
>
> Thus all the positive integral values of ₁ so that the value 2017 appears in the sequence are: 
>   ₁ ∈ { 93; 1943; 1980; 2017 }

I was searching up the same question, and I came up across this answer. Can somebody explain it to me, as I'm having a bit of trouble understanding it. Also, is it a correct proof? Yahoo has lots of wrong answers, according to my experience. I'm particularly worried about the second step, where the person has added a coefficient to $x$ for reasons I don't understand. Also, I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding what the variable $n$ is meant to be.

Comment: Downvoter please comment

Comment: Don't provide links, but rather type out the entire question/discussion.

Comment: @Math_QED I've edited the question and now the whole question and answer are in my question

Comment: Good job. I upvoted to undo my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This proof looks fine to me.

> added a coefficient to x for reasons I don't understand

$x$ is just the name he gives to the unknown first seed. Then he repeatedly applies the formula
$$u_{n+3} = u_{n} + u_{n+1} + u_{n+2}$$
to find the $n$th element in terms of $x$.

> understanding what the variable n is meant to be

$$u_{n+3} = u_{n} + u_{n+1} + u_{n+2}$$
This defines the Tribonacci sequence, it is supposed to hold for all integer $n$. A more complete expression would be
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : u_{n+3} = u_{n} + u_{n+1} + u_{n+2}$$